# Notifications handling in apache cordova app

Tags: android, ios, phonegap-plugins, apache-cordova

I'm building an apache cordova messaging app (using javascript).

I'm looking for a way to have more control over notifications in my app.

Is there a way to receive a notification and build its text on the client device? I would like to create it in the user's proffered language and use the user's contacts names in the notification itself.

Also, I would like to be able to decide if to show a certain notification when it is received in the device (for example, don't show a notification for a group chat that was silenced)

Is it possible to do when the app is not open at all?
How is it handled differently from native android and iOS apps?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We are talking about push notifications right?

I don't remember the exact function names but think it's quite possible using cordova notification plugin.
So when app is in active/background, you will be able to get the notification object in your callback and decide whatever you do - show it in notification area using local notification, or show in-app alert or just ignore.

When app is closed, system handles the notification and shows in notification area(based on the notification payload APNS/GCMS sends) and when user taps on it, app is launched and a notification handler callback is called inside app.

Anyway, I think what you want to do is quite possible with native apps and cordova plugin since it exposes all of native functionalities.

Comment: And when the app is closed is there a way to tell the system what to do?

Comment: For example, when a user receives a message I would like to show the senders name according to the user's contact name so it has to be done locally

Comment: No way to do that when app is closed. In that case, the notification sender(your backend I assume) should handle it.

Comment: Is that the same for native apps as well?

Comment: How does popular messaging apps use my contacts name in notifications when they are closed?

Comment: Yes, it's the same for native apps, since the underlying functionalities the OS SDKs provide are the same.

Comment: Popular messaging apps - they do some logic on their own, so when I send message to you, their server checks their user DB and pull my name saved on your side and do some string operations to make a full text and sends it as a push notification.